# How can I get the appointment status on the Release Time Activities screen

Tags: acumatica

I'm customizing the Release Time Activities screen (EP507020) in the following ways:

First, I'm putting the Appointment Number in the grid via the 'Add Data Fields' option in the screen customization.

Second, I want to tie back to the Appointments screen (FS300200) via the Appointment Nbr to get the status.

Third, I want to add a user field to the Time Activities grid to hold this obtained status so that the grid can be filtered by the status.

I've run into several problems, the largest of which is that even though I can add the Appointment Number to the Release Time Activities screen grid - and upon inspection it shows that it belongs to the same DAC as all the other fields in that grid - it show NO WHERE in the DAC when I bring up the source code.  It isn't in any table I can find either.  This is a complete mystery - how can a field show on the inspection window as part of a DAC when it really isn't?

Next - there are two fields in the DAC for the Appointments screen DAC (FSAppointment) - RefNbr (which is the Appointment Number) and the AppointmentID (which is an auto-incrementing identity field).  Which one would I use to tie back to the Appointments screen to link the Appointment Nbr (if that's even possible)?

The main issue is that I cannot find the Appointment Nbr in the DAC (EPActivityApprove) to even tie back to the Appointments screen.

Is this something doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Activity dataview bound to Release Time Activities screen (EP507020) grid contains multiple DACs:

```
public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<
    EPActivityApprove,
    EPActivityFilter,
    LeftJoin<EPEarningType,
        On<EPEarningType.typeCD, Equal<EPActivityApprove.earningTypeID>>,
    InnerJoin<EPEmployee,
        On<EPEmployee.userID, Equal<EPActivityApprove.ownerID>,
        And<Where<EPEmployee.timeCardRequired, NotEqual<True>, Or<EPEmployee.timeCardRequired, IsNull>>>>,
    LeftJoin<CRActivityLink,
        On<CRActivityLink.noteID, Equal<EPActivityApprove.refNoteID>>,
    LeftJoin<CRCase,
        On<CRCase.noteID, Equal<CRActivityLink.refNoteID>>,
    LeftJoin<CRCaseClass,
        On<CRCaseClass.caseClassID, Equal<CRCase.caseClassID>>,
    LeftJoin<ContractEx,
        On<CRCase.contractID, Equal<ContractEx.contractID>>>>>>>>
        [...]
```

Looking at the main DAC we see it extends PMTimeActivity so it will contain all fields of that DAC too:

```
public class EPActivityApprove : PMTimeActivity
```

PMTimeActivity doesn't contain AppointmentID either but another DAC named FSxPMTimeActivity does and it also extends PMTimeActivity. That's the reason why you're seeing that field available in EPActivityApprove:

```
public class FSxPMTimeActivity : PXCacheExtension<PMTimeActivity>
{
        #region AppointmentID
        public abstract class appointmentID : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }

        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Appointment Nbr.")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<FSAppointment.appointmentID>),
                           SubstituteKey = typeof(FSAppointment.refNbr))]
        public virtual int? AppointmentID { get; set; }
        #endregion
}
```

Given an EPActivityApprove object I think you can get a reference to the extension containing AppointmentID like this:

```
EPActivityApprove row = ???;
FSxPMTimeActivity rowExt = row.GetExtension<FSxPMTimeActivity>();
int? appointmentID = rowExt.AppointmentID;
```

As for the joins, you must specify each key field (IsKey = true) from the DAC.
For FSAppointment these would be SrvOrdType and RefNbr (appointmentID is not a key field in that DAC):

```
#region SrvOrdType
public abstract class srvOrdType : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}

[PXDBString(4, IsFixed = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = ">AAAA")]
[PXDefault(typeof(FSSetup.dfltSrvOrdType))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Service Order Type")]
[FSSelectorSrvOrdTypeNOTQuote]
[PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
public virtual string SrvOrdType { get; set; }
#endregion

#region RefNbr
public abstract class refNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}

[PXDBString(20, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Appointment Nbr.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Visible = true, Enabled = true)]
[PXSelector(typeof(
    Search2<FSAppointment.refNbr,
    LeftJoin<FSServiceOrder,
        On<FSServiceOrder.sOID, Equal<FSAppointment.sOID>>,
    LeftJoin<Customer, 
        On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<FSServiceOrder.customerID>>,
    LeftJoin<Location, 
        On<Location.locationID, Equal<FSServiceOrder.locationID>>>>>,
    Where<
        FSAppointment.srvOrdType, Equal<Optional<FSAppointment.srvOrdType>>>,
    OrderBy<Desc<FSAppointment.refNbr>>>),
            new Type[] {
                        typeof(FSAppointment.refNbr),
                        typeof(Customer.acctCD),
                        typeof(Customer.acctName),
                        typeof(Location.locationCD),
                        typeof(FSAppointment.docDesc),
                        typeof(FSAppointment.status),
                        typeof(FSAppointment.scheduledDateTimeBegin)
            })]
[AppointmentAutoNumber(typeof(
    Search<FSSrvOrdType.srvOrdNumberingID,
    Where<
        FSSrvOrdType.srvOrdType, Equal<Optional<FSAppointment.srvOrdType>>>>),
    typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
[PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]
public virtual string RefNbr { get; set; }
#endregion
```

**EDIT:**
Took a better look at it, I don't think you'll be able to join on the key fields. Because AppointmentID is a Unique Identifier field you can make an exception in this case and join only on that field because it will behave as a single key field.

Comment: Thanks much - but I gotta ask - Where would I have found 'FSxPMTimeActivity'?  How did you know that existed?

Comment: I went to Source Code page (SM204570) and I searched for "int? AppointmentID". I already found out that EPActivityApprove extends PMTimeActivity so I was specifically looking for a DAC that has AppointmentID and that extends PMTimeActivity. Looking at all results FSxPMTimeActivity matched both conditions so I knew this had to be the one. Field Service module was initially developed by a third party and was subsequently integrated into Acumatica. That explains some discrepancies between that module and other parts of the software developed in-house.